# Python Pandas DataFrame adding a fixed value from list to cloumn and Generating new Column output for each of this list values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This may be a different in requirements

i have data frame

```
 A  B  C
 1  2  4
 2  4  6
 8  10 12
 1  3  5
```

and a dynamic list (the length may vary
list`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
I wish to add C colum value with list value  with each of this list and generate new dataframe column with added value how to do this?

```
 A  B  C  C_1  C_2 .......................... C_11
 1  2  4  5     6                             15
 2  4  6  7     8                             17
 8  10 12 11    14
 1  3  5  6     7                             16
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: what are the values of the column?

Comment: @Datanovice the column value will be sum of C and list element value,I am yet to get the final output .Try if you find some solution

Comment: edited post, I think I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a dict comprehension to create a simple dataframe.

```
dynamic_vals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]


df2 = pd.concat(
 [df,pd.DataFrame({f'C_{val}' : [0] for val in dynamic_vals })]
                                              ,axis=1).fillna(0)

print(df2)


   A   B   C  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4  C_5  C_6  C_7  C_8  C_9  C_10  C_11
0  1   2   4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
1  2   4   6  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
2  8  10  12  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
3  1   3   5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0
```

or you could use `assign` again with the suggestion of @piRSqaured

```
df2 = df.assign(**dict((f'C_{i}', np.nan) for i in dynamic_vals))


   A   B   C  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4  C_5  C_6  C_7  C_8  C_9  C_10  C_11
0  1   2   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2   4   6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2  8  10  12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
3  1   3   5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

or better and more simple solution suggested by @piRSquare

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, df.index, dynamic_vals).add_prefix('C_')

   A   B   C  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4  C_5  C_6  C_7  C_8  C_9  C_10  C_11
0  1   2   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2   4   6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
2  8  10  12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
3  1   3   5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

## Edit :

Using `df.join` with a dictionary comprehension.

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame({f'C_{val}' : df['C'].values + val for val in dynamic_vals }))

   A   B   C  C_1  C_2  C_3  C_4  C_5  C_6  C_7  C_8  C_9  C_10  C_11
0  1   2   4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14    15
1  2   4   6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16    17
2  8  10  12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21    22    23
3  1   3   5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15    16
```

Comment: Also `df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, df.index, dynamic_vals).add_prefix('C_'))`

Comment: Using your `assign` technique: `df.assign(**dict((f'C_{i}', np.nan) for i in dynamic_vals))`

Comment: awesome thanks for the tips @piRSquared will defo take them into account going forward

Comment: NP, you've got great answers.  GOGO 10K! (-:

Comment: @Datanovice adding prefix is fine thank you for that ,how to sum the C column vlaue with each of this list value and place in C_1 ,C_2... C_11,May be i missed in the original question ,just edited it.please check